# Should I switch off my WiFi extender when I am not using it?

Tags: wireless-networking

After I am done in the kitchen using my laptop or tablet, should I turn off my WiFi extender or just keep it on? I am not sure what to do about this.

Comment: There is no real reason why to do it nor is there one why to not do it. That makes the answer to this question primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely up to your decision will you leave your Wi-Fi range extender turned on, or switch it off when it is not in use.

Regarding *power consumption* it is *very small*, almost negligible, e.g. my *TP-Link TL-WA850RE power consumption* is 3 W (*504 Wh weekly*, or *26,28 kWh yearly*).

I leave it **ON** because it is (for me) unpractical to wait for boot of the device every time I switch it on/plug it in.

But if your range extender is in the sleeping room or near your (or others) head... well, that is completely different, health regarding, subject.